# Java : transform float to string and keep 9 number after dot

Tags: java, casting, floating-point, precision, bigdecimal

When i want to transform Float like "1234.5678930E8F" to Long/BigDecimal/String format/type , i don't get "123456789300" for example :

```
    Float test = 1234.5678930E8F;
    BigDecimal testB = new BigDecimal( test, MathContext.DECIMAL64 );
    System.out.println( testB );
    System.out.println( test );
    System.out.println( test.longValue() );
```

In out i get :

```
 123456790528
 1.23456791E11
 123456790528
```

But i need value with precision .

Comment: Have you tried using DecimalFormat?

Comment: It's hopeless.  Your initial `float` doesn't have as much precision in the first place as you hope to get out of the transformed representations.  `float` (and therefore `Float`) has about 7 decimal digits of precision, but you want to retain 11 digits.  The data just aren't there, notwithstanding what you've written in your source.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Yes and i get the same result .

Answer (score 0):

Well After a lot of testing use `Double` instead of `Float` for better precision. As John Bollinger suggest.

```
    Double testing = 1234.5678930E8;
    BigDecimal testB = new BigDecimal( testing, MathContext.DECIMAL64 ).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);;
    System.out.println( testB);
```

OutPut:

```
123456789300.00
```

Check more about Rounding in this [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Yes , it's impossible,  Thank you !